# Evitar ingeniería inversa y decompilación de .apk o .abb en android

Tags: android, android-studio, seguridad, ingeniería-inversa, ofuscación

Tengo intención de publicar una app android en la Store. Estoy buscando información para evitar la ingeniería inversa y no veo nada más que el uso de ofuscadores como proguard, los cuales por lo que he visto se pueden saltar.
Me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de evitar por completo la ingeniería inversa e impedir que a través de la apk puedan acceder al código fuente, tanto para evitar copias como por algunos datos como keys de APIs.

Es la primera app que voy a publicar y no se que es lo habitual y recomendable hacer antes de subirla. Agradecería también saber cuales son los pasos recomendados antes de publicarla por si me estoy saltando algo importante, ya que ahora mismo solo pasaría el código fuente por proguard y después la publicaría en la Store.

Comment: Una vez me dijeron y lo volvi a leer en muchos lados, que si tenes que preguntar esto, entonces tu aplicacion es una mas del monton, y no, no le va a pasar nada. Si tu codigo fuera magico, entonces seguramente podrias hacer magia con el. Pero tu codigo es replicable mas alla de que lo ofusques o no. Ni te preocupes, hace lo que quieras, y olvidate. Quien quiera conseguir tu codigo, lo va a conseguir hagas lo que hagas... una vez que esta afuera, ya no es tuyo...

Comment: Cómo dijo gbianchi, no es necesario que alguien tenga el código original para crear una réplica funcional de cualquier proyecto. Otra razón por la que tal vez quieras ocultar tu código es para evitar que código sensible pueda ser modificado por alguien con malas intenciones.

Comment: Podrías combinar el uso de proguards con cositas de cmake, algo como esto:
https://www.codementor.io/blog/kotlin-apikeys-7o0g54qk5b

Answer (score 1):

> Me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de evitar por completo la
> ingeniería inversa e impedir que a través de la apk puedan acceder al
> código fuente, tanto para evitar copias como por algunos datos como
> keys de APIs.

**En realidad no existe hasta el día de hoy un método infalible para evitar la ingeniería inversa**, puedes usar proguard para realizar una ofuscación de tu código.

Pero para "esconder" información sensible como es el caso de las `API Key`, puedes guardar estos valores en tu archivo `gradle.properties` para que no se puedan obtener por ingeniería inversa, esto es recomendado por Google:

Lo correcto en Android para esconder información sensible, es definir esta información dentro de tu archivo gradle.properties, ejemplo:

```
SECRET_CLIENT_API_KEY=key=AIzaSyJorgeSysIsCoOlaeB12GSET-U
SECRET_TOKEN_API_KEY=key=AIzaS12JorgeSysIsCoOlsauPrOsTaeB12GSET-U
```

y definir la referencia de estos valores dentro del archivo app/build.gradle:

```
android {
    ...
    ...
    defaultConfig {
    ...
    ...
    ...
        //Defined in gradle.properties
        buildConfigField "String", "SECRET_CLIENT_API_KEY", "\"$SECRET_CLIENT_API_KEY\""
        buildConfigField "String", "SECRET_TOKEN_API_KEY", "\"$SECRET_TOKEN_API_KEY\""
    }

}
```

al generar tu proyecto se generará la clase BuildConfig que contendrá los valores y que podrás asignar a tu aplicación al realizar la compilación, y estos no se podrán obtener mediante ingeniería inversa.

```
//Obtiene valores escondidos.
val myApiKey = BuildConfig.SECRET_TOKEN_API_KEY
val mySecretToken = BuildConfig.SECRET_TOKEN_API_KEY
```

revisa esta respuesta

[Se puede guardar información privada en una carpeta assets en android al momento de crear una app](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/557091/se-puede-guardar-informaci%c3%b3n-privada/558020#558020)